# Compare multiple date fields in JSON and use them in where clause

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, filter, where-clause

So i have a text field in my Postgres 10.8 (json_array_elements not possible) DB. It has a json structure like this.

```
{
  "code_cd": "02",
  "tax_cd": null,
  "earliest_exit_date": [
    {
      "date": "2023-03-31",
      "_destroy": ""
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-11-01",
      "_destroy": ""
    },
    {
      "date": "2021-12-21",
      "_destroy": ""
    }
  ],
  "enter_date": null,
  "leave_date": null
}
```

earliest exit_date can also be empty like this:

```
{
  "code_cd": "02",
  "tax_cd": null,
  "earliest_exit_date":[],
  "enter_date": null,
  "leave_date": null
}
```

Now i want to get the earliest_exit_date back where the date is after current_date and is the closest one to current_date. From the example with earliest_exit_date the output have to be: 2021-12-21

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If your table has unique value or has id you can use below query:

Sample table and data structure: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e0c9104a202a32aac7d80b4b8b14feb8)

```sql
select distinct
  id,
  min("date") filter (where "date" > current_date) over (partition by id)
from 
  test t
  cross join jsonb_to_recordset(t.data::jsonb -> 'earliest_exit_date') as e("date" date)
order by id
```

Comment: Strange i implemented your code but i get null everywhere in the date column..

Comment: This is [sample query](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=09277eaf1230938dc6c490c26f678444), but in my opinion, you have too many records, and I change the query and wrote it with window function